Amplify Refresh Token
I'm using AWS Amplify for authentication and need to include a device key in Cognito's pre-token generation Lambda function during the refresh token flow. How can I access or pass the device key to the pre-token generation function when Amplify refreshes the token?

you should use Use Cognito's device tracking or a custom attribute to store the device key then Fetch the device key in the PreTokenGeneration Lambda function and modify the token as needed final step be sure the PreTokenGeneration Lambda trigger is correctly configured and tested.

@SamirGuiderk
I'm already using Cognito's device tracking, but since 10 people are using the same account on different devices at the same time, I need to identify which specific device is refreshing its token.

@SamirGuiderk Although Amplify is passing device tracking information, I'm not seeing the device key in the event object within the PreTokenGeneration Lambda function during the REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH flow.
{
"AuthFlow": "REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH",
"AuthParameters": {
"DEVICE_KEY": "eu-west-1_b880bcaf-95f9-4997-a9cd-a44e4cf04c6a",
"REFRESH_TOKEN": "",
"ClientId": "*"
},
}

The DEVICE_KEY that you put in the AuthParameters during the REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH flow is processed by Cognito internally for device tracking and validation but is not passed to the PreTokenGeneration in your Lambda. The Lambda function only receives the validated user attributes and claims-related data.
To include the DEVICE_KEY in the PreTokenGeneration Lambda, you will need to store it in a place where it becomes part of the event object or is retrievable during the refresh token, I will give an example of a solution that you can use in your lambda function

can you show me your code of the lamba function where the token is refreshed ?
